# Can you upload a custom struct to a Firestore using Swift

Tags: swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am creating an app where I have a custom struct called Piece. This piece has a string name, a string location, and a map/ dict. Is there a way to save this to Firestore?

Example code but this is what I will need to upload.

```
struct Piece {
    name = 2222
    location = "Drawer-1"
    quantities = ["blue" : 1, "red" : 3]
}
```

This is my first post ever so sorry if I do things wrong format-wise.

Comment: Show the code for the struct

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yes - this is possible. I wrote a long blog post about this: [Mapping Firestore Data in Swift - The Comprehensive Guide](https://peterfriese.dev/posts/firestore-codable-the-comprehensive-guide/).

In your case, here is how you would do this:

First, make your struct (and the `Quantity` struct) codable:

```swift
struct Piece: Codable {
  @DocumentID var id: String?
  var name: Int // are you sure that a field containing a number like 2222 should be called "name"?
  var location: String
  var quantities: [Quantity]
}

struct Quantity: Codable {
  var color: String
  var amount: Int
}
```

Then, create a class for accessing Firestore. You can name it `PieceStore` or `PieceRepository`, whatever you like.

```swift
class PieceStore {
  func addPiece(piece: Piece) {
    let collectionRef = db.collection("pieces")
    do {
      let newDocReference = try collectionRef.addDocument(from: piece)
      print("Piece stored with new document reference: \(newDocReference)")
    }
    catch {
      print(error)
    }
  }
}
```

See the blog post for more details about fetching data using one-time fetches and snapshot listeners (which will give you that cool real-time sync that Firestore is famous for).